# Grouping names for table column headings in RMarkdown for Word/docx output

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, pander

I want to group column names in an RMarkdown table for the Word/docx output.

Using `pandoc.table`:

```
library(pander)
pandoc.table(mtcars[1:3, 1:4], style = "rmarkdown") 

|       &nbsp;        |  mpg  |  cyl  |  disp  |  hp  |
|:-------------------:|:-----:|:-----:|:------:|:----:|
|    **Mazda RX4**    |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |
|  **Mazda RX4 Wag**  |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |
|   **Datsun 710**    | 22.8  |   4   |  108   |  93  |
```

This produces the output below, which is fine

[image: rmarkdown output]

But, say I want to group `mpg` & `cyl` in one group, and `disp` & `hp` in another like so (modified by hand):

```
|                     |     group1    |     group2    |
|:-------------------:|:-------------:|:-------------:|
|       &nbsp;        |  mpg  |  cyl  |  disp  |  hp  |
|:-------------------:|:-----:|:-----:|:------:|:----:|
|    **Mazda RX4**    |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |
|  **Mazda RX4 Wag**  |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |
|   **Datsun 710**    | 22.8  |   4   |  108   |  93  |
```

This won't work and the output looks like this:

[image: modified rmarkdown output]

If possible, I would also like to add the title in a merged top cell, like so (obviously this also does not work):

```
|**Table 1.** This is a table title ..........xxxxxx  |
|possibly wrapped to the next line.                   |
|:---------------------------------------------------:|
|                     |     group1    |     group2    |
|:-------------------:|:-------------:|:-------------:|
|       &nbsp;        |  mpg  |  cyl  |  disp  |  hp  |
|:-------------------:|:-----:|:-----:|:------:|:----:|
|    **Mazda RX4**    |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |
|  **Mazda RX4 Wag**  |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |
|   **Datsun 710**    | 22.8  |   4   |  108   |  93  |
```

Comment: That's not possible as per [Pandoc's markdown table definitions](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables) -- there's no support for column or row spanning. There are some very limited workarounds, like what we do in `pander.CrossTable`, but that's relatively tricky and not elegant at all.

Comment: @daroczig the solution does not have to be using `pander`, are there any other alternatives? If not, could you still provide an example using `pander.CrossTable` ?

Comment: if you're only targeting pdf output, you can always use [raw latex](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#raw-tex)

Comment: @Mihael As said, it's not a `pander` limitation, but limitation of the markdown specification. If your required output is Word/docx, you cannot use even use the more customizable HTML or LaTeX. An option is to do HTML output and import to Word, or check eg the ReporteRs package for Word output from R.